# Assign group to elements of a vector based on a second vector in R

Tags: r, vector, split

Let's assume I have a vector *test*.

```
test<-c(7,4,6,8,9,7,10,2,11,15)
```

And a second vector  *test_split*.

```
test_split<-c(2,4,3,1)
```

I would to create a dataframe, where the first column is *test* and the second column is

```
(1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4)
```

As you can see this vector is made from *test_split*:

I repeat 2 (= *test_split[1]*) times 1, then 4 (= *test_split[2]*) times 2 etc.

Is there an efficient way to do that ?

Best,

W

Comment: `data.frame(test, test_split = rep(seq_along(test_split), test_split))`

Comment: Try `rep(seq_along(test_split), test_split)`

Comment: `unlist(Map(rep, 1:4, test_split))`?